# Is there a more secure way to request access_token in OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

Tags: post, twitter, https, oauth-2.0, pkce

I have this typescript `req_access_token` function to get the access token from the twitter api. I'm passing the `code_verfier` in the `url` variable and I guess this is not the most secure way but this is also the only way it's working for me. How can I attach these values to the POST request more securely?

```js
    async function req_access_token(code: string, verfier: string, state: string) {
        let url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token'
        url += '?grant_type=authorization_code'
        url += '&client_id=' + process.env.CLIENT_ID
        url += '&client_secret=' + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
        url += '&redirect_uri=' + 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth'
        url += '&code=' + code
        url += '&code_verifier=' + verfier

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + generate_CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT_AUTH_HEADER(),
        },
    })
    
        const json = await response.json()
        return json
}
```

Comment: Is your `code_verifier` hashed? I believe not as i can't see a `code_challenge_method` but want to double check.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual to POST the values like this, which seems to match [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token#:%7E:text=Your%20users%20will%20be%20able,did%20not%20authorize%20your%20App).

```js
const formData = new URLSearchParams();
formData.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
formData.append('clientId', myclient);
formData.append('code', code);
formData.append('redirect_uri', myredirectUri);
formData.append('code_verifier', codeVerifier);

const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: formData
}
```

I imagine it works in the URL due to generic retrieval of parameter values server side. Also, avoid use of a client secret in JavaScript since it can't be kept safe there. A cloent secret is typically used when routing to Twitter via a backend component.